# R Newbie: Saving outputs of a loop to a matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I have a short script that simulates a physical process with sampling from two different distributions. See comments. How can I put the iteration results into a matrix for further statistical analysis? I have looked at previous answered questions but still can’t get it to work. I understand that if loops are not the preferred method in R, but loops is what I understand based on rudimentary Perl and Python, everything else would confuse me.

```
library(truncnorm)                                      
library(mc2d)                                       
o <- 0.04                                       
n <- 10     # number of random samples - kept low for debugging 
md <- seq(0,0.70,by=0.05)   # md for mode in the PERT distribution  
for(i in md) {  # iterates over all modes in PERT distribution                      
f <- rpert(n, min=0, mode=md, max=.99, shape=4) # samples from PERT distribution                            
a <- rtruncnorm(n, a=0, b=Inf, mean = 5.44, sd = 0.43)  # samples from normal distribution                  

ma <- a*(1-f)+ f*o # calculates results                         

print(ma)   # I need this in a matrix
}
```

Comment: Forget what you know from other programming languages. Instead remember your algebra classes and think in vectors. If you want to do something for every single element of a vector, chances are high that there is a function that can do it for the whole vector at once.

Comment: Hi @Klaus, does any of the answers below answer your question? If so, feel free to accept whatever answer you found most helpful by clicking on the `v` sign next to it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tour If your issue has not been resolved, feel free to provide clarifications as to what does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see how the results of the loop depend on `i`, so the loop can be avoided with no complication by directly using matrices.

```
library(truncnorm); library(mc2d)                                       
o <- 0.04; n <- 10
md <- seq(0,0.70,by=0.05)

pertmat <- matrix(rpert(n*length(md), min=0, mode=md, max=.99, shape=4),
                  ncol=n, nrow=length(md))
amat <- matrix(rtruncnorm(n*length(md), a=0, b=Inf, mean = 5.44, sd = 0.43), 
               ncol=n, nrow=length(md))        

finalmat <- amat*(1-pertmat) + pertmat*o
```

Note that at the moment, you pass the entire vector `md` into the `rpert` function as an argument. If you wanted to pass single elements of `md`, you would have to change the `md` argument into `i` instead. More explicitly, compare the following two outputs for a shorter `md` vector (to avoid cluttering screen space):

```
short_md <- seq(0,0.70,by=0.35)
for(i in short_md) print(i) # single elements 
[1] 0
[1] 0.35
[1] 0.7
for(i in short_md) print(short_md) # in each iteration, the entire vector is used
[1] 0.00 0.35 0.70
[1] 0.00 0.35 0.70
[1] 0.00 0.35 0.70
```

To get a matrix from this, you could use:

```
 pertmat_i <- t(sapply(md, function(x) rpert(n, min=0, mode=x, max=.99, shape=4)))
```

and then use this matrix above.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an empty matrix with the desired number of columns and then `rbind` the simulated result into the matrix dynamically:

```
library(truncnorm)                                      
library(mc2d)                                       
o <- 0.04                                       
n <- 10     # number of random samples - kept low for debugging 
md <- seq(0,0.70,by=0.05)   # md for mode in the PERT distribution  

resultMatrix <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = n)
for(i in md) {  # iterates over all modes in PERT distribution                      
    f <- rpert(n, min=0, mode=md, max=.99, shape=4) # samples from PERT distribution                            
    a <- rtruncnorm(n, a=0, b=Inf, mean = 5.44, sd = 0.43)  # samples from normal distribution                          
    ma <- a*(1-f)+ f*o # calculates results                         
    resultMatrix <- rbind(resultMatrix, ma)
}

resultMatrix
       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]
ma 4.871186 4.527776 6.155239 2.687423 3.172824 4.150493 4.309858 4.058311
ma 4.492796 4.023142 5.202100 3.549102 3.121166 4.030550 4.072121 4.754218
ma 5.209793 3.604659 4.546211 4.019750 4.230491 2.230483 5.321552 4.194712
ma 5.588713 5.845059 4.673996 5.068933 4.445595 2.556984 3.206710 2.198054
ma 5.161478 4.224916 4.731809 4.337504 5.279807 4.800994 1.920244 2.287079
ma 4.370172 4.174557 4.657961 3.551273 3.176608 1.967586 2.082636 2.382379
ma 4.752645 5.025765 4.077100 4.035936 3.696961 4.376170 4.756229 3.799819
ma 4.895087 4.476946 4.849364 4.948230 4.254575 2.860149 4.385260 4.909378
ma 4.600699 2.955893 4.011127 5.018648 3.446420 2.684369 3.733717 3.784529
ma 3.015752 5.150226 4.641076 5.403140 1.566149 4.467812 2.624535 4.140788
ma 5.126098 4.311545 3.244769 2.922413 5.712901 2.981147 2.106302 4.173604
ma 4.497303 5.128249 2.420177 3.460802 3.158532 1.826757 3.705091 2.092096
ma 5.133561 3.937170 5.159742 3.097803 3.157485 4.583058 3.529645 5.299575
ma 5.384795 5.977110 4.269142 3.898964 5.024477 2.174062 4.364693 2.060221
ma 4.963641 4.670167 3.732576 5.075890 3.384682 3.581102 2.846963 4.388798
       [,9]    [,10]
ma 2.035035 3.047999
ma 3.119995 1.962640
ma 5.107974 3.442291
ma 2.810294 1.258326
ma 2.951629 2.220695
ma 4.461524 2.804621
ma 3.077005 5.595100
ma 1.248858 3.427024
ma 1.983569 2.546225
ma 1.510322 2.482890
ma 4.652874 1.692841
ma 4.029131 4.909566
ma 3.502746 2.017282
ma 1.992627 3.583658
ma 3.336058 3.147302
```

Comment: This could be very slow for large md. Dynamically growing objects, e.g., with `rbind()` is often a major performance bottleneck and is generally not considered good practice. I would suggest allocating the required dimensions of `resultMatrix` at its definition before the loop and filling the rows with data by using the row index within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
output <- matrix(

  unlist(

    lapply(md, function(md){

      f <- rpert(n, min=0, mode=md, max=.99, shape=4) # samples from PERT distribution                            
      a <- rtruncnorm(n, a=0, b=Inf, mean = 5.44, sd = 0.43)  # samples from normal distribution                  
      ma <- a*(1-f)+ f*o # calculates results  

    })

  ),

  ncol=10, byrow=TRUE

)
```